# EMail is not sending

Tags: linux, email, email-server, exim, email-bounces

I'm running exim with a CPanel setup. However, I am checking var/log/exim_rejectlog and am not seeing a single issue going to this hotmail account. its just not listed. but the email is not going in.

i tried this:

```
exim -bt MYEMAIL@hotmail.com
MYEMAIL@hotmail.com
  router = lookuphost, transport = remote_smtp
  host mx4.hotmail.com [65.54.188.72]  MX=5
  host mx4.hotmail.com [65.54.188.94]  MX=5
  host mx4.hotmail.com [65.55.37.88]   MX=5
  host mx4.hotmail.com [65.55.37.104]  MX=5
  host mx4.hotmail.com [65.55.92.136]  MX=5
  host mx4.hotmail.com [65.55.92.152]  MX=5
  host mx4.hotmail.com [65.55.92.184]  MX=5
  host mx4.hotmail.com [65.54.188.110] MX=5
  host mx4.hotmail.com [65.55.37.120]  MX=5
  host mx4.hotmail.com [65.54.188.126] MX=5
  host mx4.hotmail.com [65.55.92.168]  MX=5
  host mx4.hotmail.com [65.55.37.72]   MX=5
root@ns1 [~]# exim -bh 65.54.188.72

**** SMTP testing session as if from host 65.54.188.72
**** but without any ident (RFC 1413) callback.
**** This is not for real!

>>> host in hosts_connection_nolog? no (option unset)
LOG: SMTP connection from [65.54.188.72]
>>> host in host_lookup? no (option unset)
>>> host in host_reject_connection? no (option unset)
>>> host in sender_unqualified_hosts? no (option unset)
>>> host in recipient_unqualified_hosts? no (option unset)
>>> host in helo_verify_hosts? no (option unset)
>>> host in helo_try_verify_hosts? no (option unset)
>>> host in helo_accept_junk_hosts? yes (matched "*")
>>> using ACL "acl_smtp_connect"
>>> processing "accept"
>>> check hosts = +trustedmailhosts
>>> sender host name required, to match against lsearch;/etc/trustedmailhosts
>>> looking up host name for 65.54.188.72
>>> IP address lookup yielded bay0-mc1-f.bay0.hotmail.com
>>> gethostbyname2 looked up these IP addresses:
>>>   name=bay0-mc1-f.bay0.hotmail.com address=65.54.188.72
>>> checking addresses for bay0-mc1-f.bay0.hotmail.com
>>>   65.54.188.72 OK
>>> host in "lsearch;/etc/trustedmailhosts"? no (end of list)
>>> host in "+trustedmailhosts"? no (end of list)
>>> accept: condition test failed in ACL "acl_smtp_connect"
>>> processing "accept"
>>> 65.54.188.72 in "iplsearch;/etc/trustedmailhosts"? no (end of list)
>>> check condition = ${if match_ip{$sender_host_address}{iplsearch;/etc/trustedmailhosts}{1}{0}}
>>>                 = 0
>>> accept: condition test failed in ACL "acl_smtp_connect"
>>> processing "accept"
>>> check hosts = +relay_hosts : +loopback
>>> host in "net-iplsearch;/etc/relayhosts"? no (end of list)
>>> host in "<; 127.0.0.0/8 ; 0.0.0.0 ; ::1 ; 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:7f00:0000/8"? no (end of list)
>>> host in "+relay_hosts : +loopback"? no (end of list)
>>> accept: condition test failed in ACL "acl_smtp_connect"
>>> processing "accept"
>>> check hosts = +relay_hosts : +backupmx_hosts
>>> host in "lsearch;/etc/backupmxhosts"? no (end of list)
>>> host in "+relay_hosts : +backupmx_hosts"? no (end of list)
>>> accept: condition test failed in ACL "acl_smtp_connect"
>>> processing "accept"
>>> check condition = ${if eq {$interface_port}{25}{no}{yes}}
>>>                 = yes
>>> accept: condition test succeeded in ACL "acl_smtp_connect"
220-ns1.MYDOMAINNAME.COM ESMTP Exim 4.80 #2 Thu, 17 Jan 2013 15:14:46 -0500
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited,
220 and/or bulk e-mail.
```

/var/log/maillog does not contain or show any information on the email.

Comment: Looks like your e-mail content or server's IP is being flagged as spam?

Comment: Locally or remotely? Not even showing up in the junk folder. Also, this is a private box used only for billing. The IP shows clean using http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to look at the mail log to see what's happening. It is usually in /var/log/ and called maillog or mail.log.

Just search for the email address in the logfile. That will tell you about each delivery attempt and either that it was successful or why it was not.

If you smarthost all your email via another provider, you will need to ask them to investigate as the logs for final delivery will be on their side.

Successfully getting emails delivered into hotmail consistently over a period of time was not an easy task (though I have not tried this for a while).

Comment: Yea, I looked at the maillog, those e-mails are not even mentioned.

Comment: in that case, are you sure it got sent (and via exim) in the first place. If they are not mentioned at ll in exim, it is highly unlikely that it got to exim in the first place.

Comment: That is what is wierd. I am using WHMCS and I tested with another e-mail account and everything worked fine but it also did not show up in the log. I see a bunch of spamd entires though.

Comment: I have no experience with WHMCS but check how email sending is configured. Sounds like it is using another SMTP server (perhaps its own?). Another thing you can do is to check the headers of the email. This will tell you each hop the email took. The first entry will tell you where it originated. This should help you pinpoint the originating server.

Comment: It's setup to use PHP MAIL. I know it send because I've had clients reply back to me. So I'm just wondering if something might be blocking hotmail maybe?

Comment: hotmail can and will block servers / reject emails for various reasons. The the easiest way to find out why (to resolve it) is to look at the logs. check your php ini (usually in /etc/php.ini) to find out how it is set to send emails. It can use the local sendmail binary (which will link to exim if that's the local default mta) or a remote smtp smarthost. If the return address from the emails you sent come back to you. You could just wait until it bounces, but that could be as much as a few days...